# How to fix as.Date params in Rmarkdown parameters

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

I am getting an error when trying to pass params dynamically. Does anyone know how to deal with the params value? Example and error below:

```
---
title: "Salmon Program"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date())`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
    keep_md: yes
params:
  glimpse: no
  Runs:
    label: Salmon Runs
    value:
    - Winter
    - Spring
    - Fall
    - LateFall
    input: select
    choices:
    - Winter
    - Spring
    - Fall
    - LateFall
    multiple: yes
  Year: 2012     
  Dates:
    input: slider
    min: !expr as.Date(paste0(params$Year, '-01-01',sep='-')) #!r as.Date("2012-01-01")
    max: !expr as.Date(paste0(params$Year, '-06-30',sep='-')) #!r as.Date("2012-12-31")
    value: !expr as.Date(c(paste0(params$Year, '-01-01',sep='-'), paste0(params$Year, '-01-14',sep='-'))) #!r c(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-04")) #Pass Year:2012 here to update sliderInput
    step: 30
---

Error in paste0(params$Year, "-01-01", sep = "-") : 
  object 'params' not found
Calls: as.Date -> paste0
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Could not evaluate expression: as.Date(paste0(params$Year, '-01-01',sep='-'))
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

The params seems to work but don't know why is throwing an error still: 

params$Year
[1] 2012

params$Dates
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-14"'
```

Comment: You are passing `params` to parameter section in the header. This seems like an inception/recursion and I suspect the objects passed as parameters are not yet available. Perhaps you could construct min/max/value in the script, not in the header?

Comment: I thought about that but I can't grasp the way to pass these parameters to the sliderInput control

Comment: At this point I would kindly ask you to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: In case what you're trying to do is not possible, you could try implementing the input menu yourself (i.e. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67959310/322912)).

Comment: I think the problem is that the Dates: value needs to be refreshed in the yaml before the sliderInput pops up. I wonder if there is a way to refresh the 'value' in the yaml before the rest of the code runs.

Comment: if I mannually run params:Dates then the sliderInput refreshes nicely when I hit the knit with parameters button. Problem is how do I run params:Dates on my yaml?